# Form and QueryStrings in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, query-string

I have a form on home.aspx that is this:

```
                    <form name="search" method="post" action="searchresults.aspx" id="searchform" runat="server">
                        <div class="searchField">
                            <input name="keywords" type="text" id="keywordSearch" value="Enter keywords" class="watermark" />
                        </div><!--end searchField-->
                        <div class="advanceSearchBox">
                            <p><b>Narrow results by:</b></p>

                            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlPopulation" runat="server" />

                            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlDatasource" runat="server" />  

                        </div><!--end advanceSearchBox-->
                        <div style="float: right; margin-right: 2px;">
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="images/go_up.png" AlternateText="GO" Width="34" Height="24" id="keywordSearchGO" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And on my searchresults.aspx.cs page I have this QueryString but its always empty:

```
 Response.Write(Request.QueryString["keywords"]);
```

Did I forget something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the opening form tag to:

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="searchresults.aspx" id="searchform" runat="server">
```

If you really want to be using query string for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

That's because QueryString is for `GET` requests, not `POST`.  You want to use `Request.Form` for posted data.

```
Response.Write(Request.Form["keywords"]);
```

Read more documentation for the Request.Form Collection [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

A post doesn't generate a query string. To access post data, you'll need to do so through the Form or Params property.

```
Request.Form["keywords"];
Request.Params["keywords"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're posting to searchresults.aspx, so you will need to access your posted variables through Request.Form or Request.Params.

```
string keyWords = Request.Form["keywords"];
```

OR

```
string keyWords = Request.Params["keywords"];
```